# Can I log serial output from ESP32 using Sparkfun's OpenLog?

Tags: esp32

I am working on a project that largely revolves around the ESP32 WROVER. The device is going to be at a remote location for testing, but I'll need to be able to get the serial output.
I think that the OpenLog might be a good solution here, but I'm not 100% positive. I've been reading this, and have come away with more questions (mostly because it is rather Arduino specific:) https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openlog-hookup-guide

My board has 4 pins broken out from the ESP32: rx, tx, vcc, gnd. Will those be sufficient to write to the OpenLog? Or do I need to figure out how to get a wire for dtr and blk (gnd?)

Do I need to somehow include the OpenLog library in my source for the ESP32 program? It is written using PlatformIO using C++, not Arduino. I am hoping that using a config.txt file I can just have it write all serial input it receives to a single file. Is that the case?

Thanks for any guidance here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference, it worked fine almost out of the box. I only needed to connect rx, tx, vcc, gnd. Then I setup the config file as outlined and plugged it in. Every time I run the ESP32, all of the output is saved to a new file. Couldn't have been simpler.